# PowerCli - cannot filter Virtual Machines by VMHost property

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli

I'm experimenting for the first time PowerCli on my VSphere environment.
I'm trying the Get-Vm filtering the results in this way and it's working fine:

Get-Vm | where MemoryGB -eq "8"

but if I try the same syntax, filtering by VMHost property, I don't get any result:

Get-Vm | where VMHost -eq "10.0.0.30"

But I have a lot of machines on the host 10.0.0.30, why it's not working?
I can see it if I use this syntax that filters the text output in the end:

Get-Vm | select name,vmhost | findstr -i .30

what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VMHost property that you're referring to is actually a VMHost object, so you may have to filter something like `Get-VM | where {$_.VMHost.Name -eq '10.0.0.30'}` in order to do a string vs. string comparison.

Comment: now that I have the answer in front of me I wonder how I did not think about it alone :D  , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-VMHost -Name "10.0.0.30" | Get-VM
```

VMHost has the property "Name".

So you can pass the name(ip) of VMHost and get the list of all vms on the hosted ip.

Link to cmndlet explanation: [https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6fb85470-f6ca-4341-858d-12ffd94d975e/4bee17f3-579b-474e-b51c-898e38cc0abb/doc/Get-VMHost.html#:~:text=Suspend%2DVMHost-,This%20cmdlet%20retrieves%20the%20hosts%20on%20a%20vCenter%20Server%20system,one%2C%20use%20the%20Server%20parameter](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6fb85470-f6ca-4341-858d-12ffd94d975e/4bee17f3-579b-474e-b51c-898e38cc0abb/doc/Get-VMHost.html#:%7E:text=Suspend%2DVMHost-,This%20cmdlet%20retrieves%20the%20hosts%20on%20a%20vCenter%20Server%20system,one%2C%20use%20the%20Server%20parameter).

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.